# override get only

Tags: c#, .net

Assuming I have:

```
public abstract class A {
    public abstract string Name { get; }
}
```

I want to use the "shortcut" for creating properties in the child class:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Instead of:

```
private string _Name;
public string Name {
    get{ return _Name; }
    set{ _Name=Name; }
}
```

But this cause compilation error since I have `set;` there

```
public class B {
    public override Name{get; set;}
}
```

How can I override only `get;`?

Comment: @yas4891: Error 43: cannot override because '....ItemsCount' does not have an overridable set accessor

Comment: @Kev Ω: did you delete all the other comments? Who should I listen?? Just leave it and let me work as I know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class B {
    private string iName;
    public override string Name{get{ return iName;}}
}
```

on a side note:
You could make your base class an interface and then override in the implementing class:

```
public interface A {
    string Name { get; }
}

public class B : A {
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, mistake in my question - class B is not abstract.

Answer (score 3):

Just implement the getter:

```
public override string Name
{
    get
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}
private string name;
```

The shorthand for a simple get + set property is great if you want a simple get + set property, but if you want something more complicated (such as a property with just a getter) you need to implement it yourself.

Short answer: **there is no shorthand way**

Comment: I am looking for the shortcut way - please see in the question.

Comment: @Naor My answer is just a long way of saying "There is no shortcut way"

Comment: @Naor: Kragen is right. If there is no way of setting the hidden field, there is no use in retrieving it.